# SQL Datetime as time query

Tags: sql, datetime, casting, datediff, dateadd

I would like the below select statement to be show as time rather than datetime.  I'm aware that a cast as solution is likely however given I am trying to Cast as a "grouped by time", I am not finding a solution.

```
SELECT 
DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0,dbo.tbReceiptLine.Time), 0) AS Hourly, 
DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, dbo.tbReceiptLine.Time) / 30 * 30, 0) AS [30 Mins]
```

I would like to show this as time only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008 onwards you can cast to `time` datatype:

```
SELECT CAST(dbo.tbReceiptLine.Time as time)
```

See [The ultimate guide to the datetime datatypes](http://www.karaszi.com/SQLServer/info_datetime.asp)